# Slow file copying/network browsing in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

The file copying on local discs and network shares, and browsing shared folders is much slower on the Windows 7 than it was on Windows XP. I'm sure everyone encountered this problem, I personally have seen it on many different computers.

What would you recommend to speed up these operations?

Answer (score 1):

Don't really think theres anything you can do, just hope that Microsoft will fix it in some update.. If thats ever gonna happen. :p

Answer (score 1):

Probably remote-differential compression [see](http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-7/slow-network-file-copy-issues-in-windows-7-caused-by-remote-differential-compression/) or google it for loads of more info.

Comment: I'm not sure if it works: http://blogs.technet.com/filecab/archive/2008/05/02/debunking-a-myth-about-remote-differential-compression.aspx

Comment: That is extremely strange. Since this is a technet site, I guess they know what they are talking about.

All I can say, is that I have seen several machines with consistently slow copying across network which have been resolved by  disabling RDC. (Although, I have to be honest and admit, I didn't actually re-enable it to see if the program re-occurred)

I wonder is it possible for some third-party app (eg Anti-virus) to use RDC if available and for this to be causing the programs.